# Узнать загрузился ли процесс

Tags: c++, winapi

Возможно ли средствами WinApi узнать, что запущенный процесс полностью загрузился?

Пример:
- запускаем notepad.exe -<большой файл на 1.4Гб> (CreateProcess)
После запуска процесс notepad.exe существует в дереве процессов и даже корректно откликается на оконные сообщения, но в этот момент он загружает файл в редактор (возможно он делает это в одном или нескольких потоках) и по факту работать с блокнотом еще нельзя.

P.S. принимаются любые идеи для решения проблемы)

P.S.S. состоянием "полностью загрузился" будем считать ожидаемое рабочее состояние процесса. Т.е. для блокнота - это блокнот открыл требуемый файл и готов к редактированию, для видеоплеера - файл загружен и готов к воспроизведению, для майнера - майнер загружен и работает/готов к работе

Comment: А Вы сначала дайте формальное определение понятию "полностью загрузился". Если Вы запускаете видеоплеер с именем видеофайла в качестве параметра, то когда можно считать, что он "полностью загрузился"? А если запускаете биткойн-майнер? А программу без GUI, вычисляющую триллион знаков числа Пи?

Comment: Есть `WaitForInputIdle`

Comment: @Yaant, я добавил в вопрос ответ, получилось расплывчато, но как есть)

Comment: Ага. А как система должна определить, какое именно состояние процесса является "ожидаемым рабочим"? Да, в некоторых случаях может помочь упомянутое `WaitForInputIdle`, но очевидно, далеко не во всех.

Comment: @Yaant, в этом и вопрос) может есть какие-нибудь лайфхаки, т.к. WaitForInputIdle тоже не показателен, если цикл сообщений живет в своем потоке

Comment: @Yaant, я понимаю, что вопрос дурацкий и правильный ответ "Нет, нельзя", т.к. слишком большое число вариаций для "ожидаемого рабочего" состояния, но вдруг кто-то знает)

Comment: Я, собственно, веду к тому, что, на мой взгляд, задача принципиально не алгоритмизуема и, соответственно, не решаема. Банальный пример: аудиоредактор, который при запуске с некоторым ключом конвертирует файл в другой формат. Тут даже у людей могут возникнуть разногласия по поводу ожидаемого состояния. Для кого-то - это окончание конвертации, а для кого-то - возможность нажать кнопку "отмена".

Comment: Мне тоже интересно, вдруг кто-то что-то предложит. Подписался на вопрос. :)